# jqgrid : setCell method > how to set class of the fourth parameter?

Tags: jqgrid

how to set the fourth parameter of the setCell method : the **class** parameter

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', **class** ,{color:'black', weightfont:'bold'});
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You can just define in your CSS file a new class like

```
.MyCell {
  color:'black';
  weightfont:'bold'
}
```

and then use

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', 'MyCell');
```

It seems to me that following will also work

$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', {color:'black', weightfont:'bold'});

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

yes this capability works: 
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', {color:'black', weightfont:'bold'});

but in addition, I would like to apply a jquery UI class to my cell, for example the .ui-state-default class

You can find the definition of setCell method at http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fi5wo.htm# 
But what's that mean about class parameter ?

Comment: you can call `$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', 'ui-state-default');` in the next line for example after ` $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', {color:'black', weightfont:'bold'});`. jqGrid just call `jQuery.addClass` for the corresponding `<td>` element of grid and with the corresponding parameters. So you can have multiple "add" operations. Don't forget to do this inside of `loadComplete` or other event handler like `onSelectRow`. Then you can be sure, that the grid is completely filled to the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot, it works now !

I simply wrote :

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid){    
  $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label','',{color:'gray', weightfont:'bold'});
  $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label', '', 'ui-state-default');
},
```

Comment: I recommend you use `gridview: true` always, especially if you allow user to display large number of rows at the same time. Then all rows (`<tr>` with the full contain) will be first collected in one Array of strings and then all added with respect of one `Array.join` operation. If you use `afterInsertRow` you break usage of `Array.join` inside of `addXmlData` or `addJSONData` implementation. So I find better to call `jqGrid('setCell',...);` one time inside of `loadComplete` event handler. Then you will have the same results, but everything will work more quickly.

Comment: If you want redefine class of all rows you can redefine `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td` in your css. If you change padding values, then it can be needed to redefine `cellLayout` option of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/celllayout/&value=cellLayout&type=1&include=1&search=1&ret=all)

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code

```
$('#'+gridTable).jqGrid('setLabel', "abc", "new Label");
```

runs perfectly

But if i tried to change it again like

```
$('#'+gridTable).jqGrid('setLabel', "new Label", "new Label123");
```

Above code not gives an error but value of label is not changing..