# Set row style on jquery grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i m using a jqgrid on asp.net mvc... i have a specific requirement....The data in the grid is list of values that are to be set on each row... and each row has a Date column... While displaying the grid, i want a different row color  on sunday and saturday.. while the rest of the rows are white.. How to achieve this in jquery jqgrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "bring colors" in your grid with respect of [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method of jqGrid (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874906/jqgrid-setcell-method-how-to-set-class-of-the-fourth-parameter/2875219#2875219) as an example) or `jQuery.addClass`, `jQuery.css` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028019/set-class-or-identifier-on-jqgrid-row-based-on-a-key-value-pair-placed-in-row-li/4028235#4028235) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025305/jqgrid-firefox-and-css-text-decoration-problem/3026421#3026421)). You should do this **after** the grid contain is loaded, for example, inside of your [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler.

If you want set `background-color` style on the cell you should understand one small problem. The class `'ui-widget-content'` used for every grid row already defines the `background-color` per `background` style (!!! not per `background-color`). So to have effects you should make changes of the `background-color` style in **one** from the following ways: 1) just use `background: yellow` instead of `background-color: yellow` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069471/jqgrid-setting-to-colums-cells-bg-color-when-clicked-columnheader/4070790#4070790)). 2) remove 'ui-widget-content' class with `jQuery.removeClass('ui-widget-content')` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931732/jqgrid-coloring-an-entire-line-in-grid-based-upon-a-cells-value/2936673#2936673)); 3) change style of the row more explicit like `$("#"+rowid)[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065197/jqgrid-is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-html-header-text-in-jav/) as an example). Choose the ways which you prefer.

Comment: @Rakesh: You don't commented this answer. Is this want you want? You can use for example custom formatting (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to place the color in the date column. For example see a simple code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626 additionally to more complex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069471/jqgrid-setting-to-colums-cells-bg-color-when-clicked-columnheader/4070790#4070790

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply.. i just now figured out how to do this.. here is what i did.. by using grid complete.  gridComplete: function () {var ids = $("#list").getDataIDs(); for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {var cell = $("#list").getCell(ids[i], "WeekDay"); if (cell == "Sunday" || cell == "Saturday") { $(this).jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], false, { background: '#086da1' });  // $("#" + ids)[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}}} but one thing i noticed is that i was not able to achieve result  with style.background.. the javascript was throwing some error..u can see the commented line