# jqGrid change row color on checkbox checked

Tags: jqgrid, background-color

I have seen many answers here re this, but none seem to work for me. And I don't understand WHY?
 `jqGrid  4.4.2`

for already checked boxes from db:

```
gridComplete: function() {
    $("input:checkbox:checked").closest('tr').addClass("redBackground");
},
```

doesn't work, but `closest('td')` or just `parent()` does change cell bg color!

and here is on change:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type='checkbox']", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
});
```

this does work for cell, but if I change to `closest('tr')` or `parent().parent()` - row color doesn't change

what am I missing?..

could this be something to do with row grouping?

```
groupingView : {
        groupField : ['Date'],
        groupColumnShow : [true],
        groupOrder: ['desc'],
        groupDataSorted : true
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to set color or background color on the row of the grid based on the data is the usage of `rowattr` callback. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) provide an example. The approach which you use should in general work too but be slowly. Typical reason could be that you specify `background-color` only in the definition of the class `redBackground`. The standard jQuery UI classes used by jqGrid use `background` CSS instead. So to change background color of the row you have to set `background-image: none` additionally to `background-color`. Some other variation of setting the color are described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123892/315935).

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the answer! I see... yes using just `background` not `background-color` did solve it for me... thank you for explanation. But I will consider the first mentioned answer you linked to. it seems reasonable.